# What is the Android Answer to Air Video Server?

Tags: video, streaming, dlna

I just switched to a Droid X and I love it. One of the things that keeps me from not needing my iPod touch is Air Video. Is there a similar system that can run on my network?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) is basically the same thing.  There are several apps that allow you to use DLNA like [Twonky](http://www.appbrain.com/app/twonky-mobile-free/com.pv.twonkyremote).

Comment: Thank you for this. Very helpful.  I can actually do this with my windows box just using media player.  like explained here fore windows users. http://www.agoraquest.com/viewtopic.php?topic=35037&forum=70

Answer (score 1):

Lifehacker published on how to use VLC-Shares to recreate Airplay with Android.  [Link](http://lifehacker.com/#!5766024/vlc+shares-streams-any-video-to-your-android-airplay+style)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Emit](http://emitapp.com). It brings Air Video functionality to Android.